# How to install scipy without mkl

Tags: python, numpy, heroku, scipy

Now I am working on Python 3.5 and trying to deploy my web application with Heroku. When I try to publish it online, Numpy+mkl is not compatible to Heroku and it can find only normal version of Numpy. So I uninstall Numpy+mkl and install normal Numpy. As Scipy installation requires numpy with mkl, I am now in trouble. I try to find Scipy wheel file but on Scipy website, all versions require numpy+mkl.

how can I find the Scipy without requirement of numpy+ mkl?

Comment: I found the solution. Read documentation for conda requirements. And add nomkl above all the libraries requiring mkl in the txt file of conda requirements

Answer (score 6):

In the comment above, @alrozac-S is referring to setting up a conda environment without MKL.  From the [Anaconda blog](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/anaconda-25-release-now-mkl-optimizations/):

> Finally, in case you do not need or want MKL, it is possible to opt out of installing MKL. We provide this option on Linux and OS X,
>   because MKL is a large package (roughly 100MB), and for many tasks it
>   is not necessary. The alternatives to MKL are OpenBLAS (for Linux),
>   and the native Accelerate Framework (for OS X). To use the non-MKL
>   versions of packages on Linux or OS X, first install Miniconda, and
>   then execute:
>
> ```
> conda install nomkl
> ```
>
> This effectively adds the nomkl feature, which makes conda prefer non-MKL versions of packages in all cases. For example, executing:
>
> ```
> conda install scipy
> ```

If you have installed Anaconda, you can create a new environment that will install packages from the PyData stack without MKL using:

```
conda create -n pynomkl python nomkl
```

Then install the packages as usual

```
conda install -n pynomkl numpy pandas scipy scikit-learn
```

Comment: Good in theory, but it failed for me today. I wonder what's wrong. I have nomkl in my created env but when I install fastai and pytorch I still see on conda confirmation dialog: mkl:  2019.0-118, and it is 200MB. What is wrong, is it one of the dependent packages that sadly still links to MKL somewhere?

Comment: Blog link no longer works, but the same info is available in the conda [documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/#uninstalling-mkl).

Comment: Also check this thread: https://github.com/conda-forge/numpy-feedstock/issues/84